# How to display radio button value on checked (not on clicked). *or pls guide me if there is better way for ecommerce product page*

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm creating an ecommerce website and I'm having issue on the pricing of product page based on radio (product) button.
The price is obtain from weight * wesell (wesell is value store in database)
Issue 1 - the price is not displayed when the page is loaded
[image]

Issue 2 - the price displayed has lots of decimal point (I tried used number_format("price",2) but it couldn't be displayed)
[image]

Below are the codes of the page

`code`

```js
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const groups = [...document.querySelectorAll(".swatch")].slice(1); // drop the first div
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgtDiv = e.target.closest(".swatch-element")
    if (tgtDiv) {
      const groupId = tgtDiv.querySelector("input[type=radio]").dataset.group;
      groups.forEach(aGroup => aGroup.classList.toggle("hide", groupId !== aGroup.id))

    }
  });
});
    function check() {
        $("#swatch-1-9").prop("checked", true);
    }
    function check2() {
        $("#swatch-1-6").prop("checked", true);
    }
    function check3() {
        $("#swatch-1-4").prop("checked", true);
    }
    function check4() {
        $("#swatch-1-1").prop("checked", true);
    }

        function displayRadioValue() {
            var ele = document.getElementsByName('length');
            
            for(i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
                if(ele[i].checked)
                document.getElementById("price").innerHTML
                        = "RM " + ele[i].value*<?php echo $product['wesell'];?>
                            
                        ;
            }
        }
```

```css
.swatch {
  margin: 1em 0;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}
.header { width:70px}
.hide { display: none; }

.swatch .header {
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}

.swatch input {
  display: none;
}

.swatch label {
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  float: left;
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 0;
  border: #ccc 1px solid;
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.swatch-element label {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.color.swatch-element label {
  padding: 0;
}

.swatch input:checked+label {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-color: transparent;
}

.swatch .swatch-element {
  float: left;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.crossed-out {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.swatch .swatch-element .crossed-out {
  display: none;
}

.swatch .swatch-element.soldout .crossed-out {
  display: block;
}

.swatch .swatch-element.soldout label {
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  -khtml-opacity: 0.6;
  -moz-opacity: 0.6;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.swatch .tooltip {
  text-align: center;
  background: gray;
  color: #fff;
  bottom: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  left: -23px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -khtml-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(10px);
  -o-transform: translateY(10px);
  transform: translateY(10px);
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  z-index: 10000;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.swatch .tooltip:before {
  bottom: -20px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.swatch .tooltip:after {
  border-left: solid transparent 10px;
  border-right: solid transparent 10px;
  border-top: solid gray 10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -13px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
}

.swatch .swatch-element:hover .tooltip {
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -khtml-opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  -o-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.swatch.error {
  background-color: #E8D2D2!important;
  color: #333!important;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.swatch.error p {
  margin: 0.7em 0;
}

.swatch.error p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.swatch.error p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.swatch.error code {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="swatch color clearfix" id="container" data-option-index="0">
  <div class="header">
    Product
  </div>
  <div data-value="black" class="swatch-element color black available">
    <div class="tooltip">black</div>
    <input id="swatch-0-black" checked name="option-0" value="0.96" type="radio" data-group="group1" checked onclick="displayRadioValue()   ">
    <label for="swatch-0-black" style="background-color: black; background-image: url(./assets/images/black.png)"><img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt=""></label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="red" class="swatch-element color red available">
    <div class="tooltip">
      red
    </div>
    <input id="swatch-0-red" name="option-0" value="1.34" type="radio" data-group="group2" onclick="check2(),displayRadioValue()">
    <label for="swatch-0-red" style="background-color: red; background-image: url(./assets/images/red.png)">
                        <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="white" class="swatch-element color white available">
    <div class="tooltip">
      white
    </div>
    <input id="swatch-0-white" name="option-0" value="1.48" type="radio" data-group="group3" onclick="check3(),displayRadioValue()">
    <label for="swatch-0-white" style="background-color: white; background-image: url(./assets/images/white.png)">
                        <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="blue" class="swatch-element color blue available">
    <div class="tooltip">
      blue
    </div>
    <input id="swatch-0-blue" name="option-0" value="1.52" type="radio" data-group="group4" onclick="check4(),displayRadioValue()">
    <label for="swatch-0-blue" style="background-color: blue; background-image: url(./assets/images/blue.png)">
                        <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="swatch clearfix" data-option-index="1" id="group1">
  <div class="header">
    Weight
  </div>
  <div data-value="small" class="swatch-element small available">
    <input id="swatch-1-9" name="length" value="0.96" type="radio" id="group4a"  checked  onclick="displayRadioValue()">
    <label for="swatch-1-9">
                        0.96g <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="swatch clearfix hide" id="group2">
  <div class="header">
    Weight
  </div>
  <div data-value="small" class="swatch-element small available">
    <input id="swatch-1-6" name="length" value="1.34" type="radio"  onclick="displayRadioValue()">
    <label for="swatch-1-6">
      1.34g
    </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="medium" class="swatch-element medium available">
    <input id="swatch-1-7" name="length" value="1.44" type="radio" id="group3b" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
    <label for="swatch-1-7">
      1.44g 
    </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="medium" class="swatch-element medium available">
    <input id="swatch-1-8" name="length" value="1.54" type="radio" id="group3c" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
    <label for="swatch-1-8">
      1.54g 
    </label>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="swatch clearfix hide" id="group3">
  <div class="header">
    Weight
  </div>
  <div data-value="small" class="swatch-element small available">
    <input id="swatch-1-4" name="length" value="1.48" type="radio" onchange="displayRadioValue()">
    <label for="swatch-1-4">
                        1.48g 
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="medium" class="swatch-element medium available">
    <input id="swatch-1-5" name="length" value="1.49" type="radio" id="group2b" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
    <label for="swatch-1-5">
                        1.49g <img class="crossed-out" src="./assets/images/soldout.png" alt="">
                        </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="swatch clearfix hide" id="group4">
  <div class="header">
    Weight
  </div>
  <div data-value="small" class="swatch-element small available">
    <input id="swatch-1-1" name="length" value="1.52" type="radio"  onclick="displayRadioValue()">
    <label for="swatch-1-1">
                        1.52g
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="medium" class="swatch-element medium available">
    <input id="swatch-1-2" name="length" value="1.54" type="radio" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
    <label for="swatch-1-2">
                        1.54g 
                        </label>
  </div>
  <div data-value="medium" class="swatch-element medium available">
    <input id="swatch-1-3" name="length" value="1.57" type="radio" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
    <label for="swatch-1-3">
                        1.57g
                        </label>
  </div>
</div>

    <div id="purchase-1293235843">
    <div class="detail-price" itemprop="price">
      <span class="price" id="price">

      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: For Issue No 2 - try like dis round() function instead of this number_format("price",2)

Comment: But I prefer to display the digits in two decimal places ><

Comment: so use like dis round("price",2)

Comment: Thanks, I tried but when I put round("ele[i].value",2) it disappear :( same with number_format(ele[i].value,2)

Comment: are you sure that you are getting value in ele[i].value.....give static value and check it like round("45454.4545",2)

Comment: yes im getting value from ele[i].value (value from radio button), to display the price (ele[i].value* 305 [value stored in database])

Comment: have you got the solution???

Comment: The problem is i dont want the value to be static, cause there is various options in the radio button idk if you read my codes. So the price should change dynamically when each radio button was clicked...

Comment: yea i know also i seen your code.... round(ele[i].value,2) i think while passing a variable you don't need to put double quotes

Comment: I tried eliminating the double quote too but still doesnt work :(

Comment: Math.round() try this

Comment: The price is displayed now, but not in decimal places @@

Comment: why you need to display price as decimal??? i think alwz price would be round off

Comment: As requested by client...

Answer (score 0):

for issue 2 use toFixed(2)
e.g.

```
const amount.toFixed(2) // 408.70
```